# How to Object array defferent index into index only one?

Tags: arrays, javascript-objects, arrayobject

From the example below.
Can we do it?

```js
[
  {
    '-MB07CLtzKAAFuQCCfD1': {id: 'pc 01'},
    '-MB07Q0ItOPwaaw5iIp8': {id: 'pc 02'}
  },
  
  {
    '-MB07uRP9PjKNj7rSKCl': { id: 'pc 03'}
  }
]
```

**How to do?**
*I want to get this output:*

```js
[
    '-MB07CLtzKAAFuQCCfD1': {id:'pc 01'},
    '-MB07Q0ItOPwaaw5iIp8': {id:'pc 02'},
    '-MB07uRP9PjKNj7rSKCl': {id:'pc 03'},
]
```

**Can i do?....**

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all keys in all the objects are different, you can you `Object.assign`

```js
console.log(Object.assign.apply({}, [
  {
    '-MB07CLtzKAAFuQCCfD1': {id: 'pc 01'},
    '-MB07Q0ItOPwaaw5iIp8': {id: 'pc 02'}
  },
  
  {
    '-MB07uRP9PjKNj7rSKCl': { id: 'pc 03'}
  }
]))
```

Comment: You’re so helpful.Thank you.